# how to remove duplicates from sql table with condition

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the below sql table and I want to remove the duplicate entries when `object_id` matches `team_name`. Basically I want unique values for `object_id`

```
session_id  object_id   team_name   user_name   user_desc
----------  ---------   ---------   ---------   -----------------
session1    user1       team1       user1       user1_description
session1    user2       team1       user2       user2_description
session1    team1       team1       user1       user1_description
session1    team1       team1       user2       user2_description
```

I want to convert the above table as below

```
session_id  object_id   team_name   user_name   user_desc
----------  ---------   ---------   ---------   -----------------
session1    user1       team1       user1       user1_description
session1    user2       team1       user2       user2_description
session1    team1       team1       null        null
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: what is `team_id` here? its not mentioned in the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
select (case when min(session_id) = max(session_id) then min(session_id) end) as session_id,
       object_id,
       (case when min(team_name) = max(team_name) then min(team_name) end) as team_name,
       (case when min(user_name) = max(user_name) then min(user_name) end) as user_name,
       (case when min(user_desc) = max(user_desc) then min(user_desc) end) as user_desc
from t
group by object_id;
```